# Should i install the "tidyverse" package if i've already installed ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, package, tidyverse

I'm extremely new to Rstudio, so I apologize if i'm asking a stupid question.
I've heard that if you already installed ggplot2, you should not install it once more, and
that you could run into problems if you do.
Since the tidyverse package includes ggplot2, and i've already installed ggplot2,
will i likely run into any problems installing tidyverse?

The only packages i've installed so far are ggplot2 and readxl, i think.

Comment: It should work fine to install the tidyverse package.

Comment: I think you will need the packages that are included in the `tidyverse` package for your data analysis etc... Have a look here <https://tidyverse.tidyverse.org/> which packages are included in `tidyverse`.  There should be no problem to install `tidyverse` package.

Comment: I’m not sure where you heard that from but I would say that’s not true. You can reinstall existing packages and it will just update to the latest version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a *problem* to install a package more than once on the same system, it's just a minor waste of time and bandwidth. (That is, I can't imagine a situation where it would actually cause a problem ...)

If you've already installed `ggplot2` then `install.packages("ggplot2")` is completely redundant.

If you want to install the rest of the tidyverse packages then `install.packages("tidyverse")` is probably sensible, *even if you have a few of those packages installed already* (unless you're paying by the byte for network downloads). You *could* figure out which packages are in tidyverse and install only the ones you didn't already have, but it would be a nuisance.

There are a few packages like `pacman` and [crancache](https://github.com/r-lib/crancache) (not itself on CRAN!) that provide slightly smarter package-installation workflows that check to see if a package is already installed/needs to be update before (re-)downloading and (re-)installing.